# select column's values if columns are not present in table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

I have a table "ExcelData" like below :

```
Id   [Title 1]   [Title 2]    [Address 1]  [Address 2]    City  State
1      A1          A2           add1         add2         X      Y
2      B1          B2           add1         add2         X      Y
```

I need a query in string form which gets the result from above table after checking each column if it exists in table or not.

```
Declare @strSQL nvarchar(max), @RecId int
set @RecId = 1
```

--- while loop will be there for @Count variable. My query is :

```
set @strSQL = 'SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='ExcelData' and COLUMN_NAME='[Title ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @Count)) THEN(SELECT '[Title ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @Count)]'
FROM ExcelData where ExcelData.Id = '+ @RecId +') ELSE NULL END AS [Title]
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='ExcelData' and COLUMN_NAME='[Email]' THEN(SELECT '[Email]' FROM ExcelData where ExcelData.Id = '+ @RecId +') ELSE NULL END AS [Email])'

Execute(@strSQL)
```

I need result if column is exist in table then value of that column and if it is not then query should return null in the column value like below:

Desired Result :

```
[Title 1]  [Title 2]  [Email]
   A1        A2        NULL
```

But I am not getting the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you dynamically the values of the [Title 1], [Title 2], [Email] columns if they exists, with a loop on the @RecId. If you can have multiple Title/Address columns, you should also implement that @Count variable.

```
DECLARE @strSQL nvarchar(max), 
        @RecId int

SET @RecId = 1

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM ExcelData WHERE Id = @RecId)
BEGIN
    SET @strSQL = '
    SELECT '+
        (case when exists (select *
                           from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                           where table_name = 'ExcelData' and
                                 column_name = 'Title 1' 
                          )
              then '[Title 1]'
              else 'NULL AS [Title 1]'
         end) + ', ' +
        (case when exists (select *
                           from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                           where table_name = 'ExcelData' and
                                 column_name = 'Title 2' 
                          )
              then '[Title 2]'
              else 'NULL AS [Title 2]'
         end) + ', ' +
         (case when exists (select *
                           from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                           where table_name = 'ExcelData' and
                                 column_name = 'Email' 
                          )
              then '[Email]'
              else 'NULL AS Email'
         end) + '
    FROM ExcelData
    WHERE Id = ' + CAST(@RecId AS varchar(50))

    EXEC sp_executesql @strSQL

    SET @RecId = @RecId + 1
END
```

Which results in:

```
Title 1 Title 2 Email
A1      A2      NULL

Title 1 Title 2 Email
B1      B2      NULL
```